# Typeclass Instance of a Dependent Type

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, dependent-type, scala-3

Let's say I have a `Display[T] { apply(t: T): Unit }` typeclass which is used in order to display instances (and I have instances for `String`, `Int`, etc.). And I also have a `TCWithDependentType[T] { type DependentType ; def apply(t: T): DependentType }` which transform `T` to `TCWithDependentType#DependentType`.

I'm trying to do display the instance of a `DependentType`, but it doesn't work because the compiler is not able to find the `Display[TCWithDependentType#DependentType]` (I assume it's this one) instance (even if it should be known at compile-time).

Here is the full example (associated Scastie is here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RXmC776DQeywLOxj2xbHQg):

```
trait TCWithDependentType[T]:
  type DependentType

  def apply(t: T): DependentType

def dependentTypeOf[T](t: T)(using
    tcWithDependentType: TCWithDependentType[T]
): tcWithDependentType.DependentType =
  tcWithDependentType(t)

given TCWithDependentType[Int] =
  new TCWithDependentType[Int]:
    type DependentType = String

    def apply(i: Int): String =
      s"${i}"

given TCWithDependentType[String] =
  new TCWithDependentType[String]:
    type DependentType = String

    def apply(i: String): String =
      s"${i}"

trait Display[T]:
  def apply(t: T): Unit

def display[T](t: T)(using displayForT: Display[T]): Unit =
  displayForT(t)

/* given [T]: Display[T] =
    new Display[T]:
        def apply(t: T): Unit =
            println(s"I display \"${t}\" which is unknown") */

given Display[String] =
  new Display[String]:
    def apply(t: String): Unit =
      println(s"I display \"${t}\" which is a String")

given Display[Int] =
  new Display[Int]:
    def apply(t: Int): Unit =
      println(s"I display \"${t}\" which is a Int")

val dv = dependentTypeOf(1)
display(dv)
```

Do you have an idea of what I'm missing in order to make this thing work?

Thanks!
Adrien.

Answer (score 3):

You lost type refinements

```
given (TCWithDependentType[Int] {type DependentType = String}) =
  new TCWithDependentType[Int]:
    type DependentType = String
    def apply(i: Int): String = s"${i}"

given (TCWithDependentType[String] {type DependentType = String}) =
  new TCWithDependentType[String]:
    type DependentType = String
    def apply(i: String): String = s"${i}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the standard `given ... with` syntax:

```
given TCWithDependentType[Int] with
  type DependentType = String

  def apply(i: Int): String =
    s"${i}"
```

That way your code looks cleaner and no type information is lost.

Comment: Sometimes there are bugs in `given ... with` https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/8882

Comment: That's unfortunate. Though it seems to work in most cases.